# Setting up my first .NET 5 + Angular project

Tags: .net, angular

I'm starting on my first proper solo project and I want to make a Web Application that displays data requested from Fantasy Premier League's API (FPL API). I know some .NET 5 and Angular, so it would be optimal to incorporate both of them for practice.

I have done some courses, but most of them involves setting up my own database. How do I go about getting data from another servers endpoint, manipulate it and then display it in an Angular App? Will the best practice be to request data through a .NET backend to alter the data there, before I get it at frontend?

I'm confused, but I hope my question is understandable. I've done alot of googling on the matter, without getting much wiser. I think I'm struggeling to find the right techincal terms to get a good Google search going...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I go about getting data from another servers endpoint, manipulate it and then display it in an Angular App? Will the best practice be to request data through a .NET backend to alter the data there, before I get it at frontend?

Good rule of thumb is to keep it simple.

Best practices are best cause they solve particular issue.
If the issue is unknown - you are heading down the road of so called cargo cult programming.

It is important to understand the **nature of your application**.

What is meant by data alteration?

If it's something like simple timestamp formatting - perhaps you can get away with having only client side.

Usual indicators for necessity of having a backend are:

- security concerns
- complex data manipulation
- storage support
- user management

Comment: Thank you for response. I don't think it will be to complex. By data alteration it I mean picking out some variables from the returned data and do some easy calculations and comparisons between them. 

I do begin to get the feeling that a backend is not necessarry at all for mye application, my desire to use it was to get good practice in both .NET and Angular at the same time. This might not be the project for it. You made some great points.